# Circular Shift of numbers by function

Tags: c, function, shift

I am writting a program to shift the numbers entered in a circular manner which i know how to by using call by value , but i am unable to the logic in call by refrence way

This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int shift(int *a, int *b, int *c);
void main()
{
    int x, y, z;

    printf("Enter x: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter y: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("Enter z: ");
    scanf("%d", &z);

    printf("Before Shift: x: %d\ty: %d\t z: %d",x,y,z);
    //call the shift function
    shift(&x, &y, &z);
    printf("\n After Shift: x: %d\ty: %d\t z: %d",x,y,z);
}
int shift(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *c;
    *c = *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = temp;
}
```

here in the last part of the code,what are the exact meaning of the shift function and how is here the address is moving from one variable to another.

Comment: Neither address is moved. There are moved  values of variables pointed to by pointers.

Comment: To understand just write in main     int temp;
    temp = z;
    z = y;
    y = x;
    x = temp;
The same occurs in the function but to access the orginal variables you need to dereference pointers that point to the variables For example this line within the function temp = *c; is equivalent to the line in main temp = z; because the pointer c points to the variable z. So to access the variable z you need to dereference the pointer c.

Comment: Sir,please can you explain what derefrencing  of pointers means as i have gone on many websites,used youtube but i am not able to understand it

Comment: Take any book on C and read about pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In C, variables are passed-by-value into functions. See [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373419/2472827) Specifically, let us re-write the programme for illustrative purposes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
static void fail(int t, int u, int v)
    { int temp; temp = v; v = u; u = t; t = temp; }
static void shift(int *a, int *b, int *c)
    { int temp; temp = *c; *c = *b; *b = *a; *a = temp; }
int main(void) {
    int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
    printf("Before: x: %d\ty: %d\t z: %d\n",x,y,z);
    fail(x, y, z);
    printf("fail:   x: %d\ty: %d\t z: %d\n",x,y,z);
    shift(&x, &y, &z);
    printf("shift:  x: %d\ty: %d\t z: %d\n",x,y,z);
}
```

The call to `fail` from `main` copies the values `(x, y, z)` to `(t, u, v)`. `(t, u, v)` are permuted, but then destroyed when the function goes out of scope and `fail` returns to `main`. The original values are unchanged.

[image: Graphical layout of the data from the programme.]

The programme then calls `shift` from `main` with the addresses of `(&x, &y, &z)` passed to `(a, b, c)`; dereferencing `(*a, *b, *c)` in `shift` is `(x, y, z)` in `main`. The variables are correctly permuted.